# How to make items belong to someone in roblox?

Tags: roblox

I was thinking about making a game and couldn't think of a way to to this:
Let's say, for example, you want to make rideable horses in your game, but only the player that owns a certain horse can ride it.

I thought about giving the horses different names and then assigning them to players. Obviously, It would be many horses, so the amount of names... don't even want to think about that. Also then I'm facing a problem: How to automatize the process, so every new player can get thier horse with no problems?

Answer (score 0):

Several ways of going about this:

1. Use datastores and have an array of horses for each user. Horses will want to be named by a unique name/id. See https://create.roblox.com/docs/scripting/data/data-stores for datastore docs.
   Every time you wish to check if a player owns a horse you can query the datastore. The advantages of doing it this way is that it will be saved for each time the player rejoins.
2. You could also save the array of players horses inside a value instance inside the player object, again assigning each horse a unique name/id. Then reference this instance each time you wish to check if a player owns a horse. The drawback of this approach is that the data won't save between sessions.
3. Finally and the method I would recommend is a mixture of the two approaches. When a player joins save their horses inside a datastore but also in a value instance as in solution 2. Then during the gameplay you can reference the value instance. When the player leaves and/or every couple of minutes you could save the content of the value instance to the datastore.The reason I would recommend this approach is because you could end up being limited by the number of requests you can make to Roblox's datastores and datastores can get pretty complicated at time especially when it comes to `pcalls`. In general you should avoid making too many datastore requests in a short space of time.